# How to add different image for each group in expandable Listview

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

In my Expandable Listview, have three groups. I want to add different three image for that group. i tried many codes, but not working.

My code:

Main Activity:

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> rightDrawerListDetail = getData();
List<String> rightDrawerListTitle = new ArrayList<String>(rightDrawerListDetail.keySet());
   adapterR = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(this, rightDrawerListTitle,rightDrawerListDetail);
    mRightDrawerList.setAdapter(adapterR);


private HashMap<String, List<String>> getData(){

    HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = mydb.getAllAddress();

    List asRider = new ArrayList();
    asRider.add("hello");

    List asRidee = new ArrayList();
    asRidee.add("hai");

    List recent = new ArrayList();
    recent.add("Success");

    expandableListDetail.put("As a Rider",asRider);
    expandableListDetail.put("As a Ridee",asRidee);
    expandableListDetail.put("My Recent Activities",recent);


    return expandableListDetail;
}
```

CustomExpandableListAdapter.java:

```
public class CustomExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private List<String> mGroups;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> mexpandableListDetail;

public CustomExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> groups,HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail) {
    mContext = context;
    mGroups = groups;
    mexpandableListDetail = expandableListDetail;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return mGroups.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return mexpandableListDetail.get(mGroups.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return mGroups.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return mexpandableListDetail.get(mGroups.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.right_drawer_group, null);
    }

    // Get the group item
    String listTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    // Set group name
    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textGroup);
    textView.setText(listTitle);
    ImageView indicator = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupIndicator);
    if (isExpanded) {
        indicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrowup);
    } else {
        indicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrowdown);
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.right_drawer_child, null);
    }

    // Get child name
    String children = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    // Set child name
    TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textChild);
    text.setText(children);

    /*convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, children, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });*/

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

Please anyone help to me!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your right_drawer_group.xml add an ImageView where you want your group image to be placed, lets say groupImage.

In your getGroupView:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.right_drawer_group, null);
}
//Set group image
ImageView groupImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupImage);
switch((String)getGroup(groupPosition))
{
 case "As a Rider":
  //groupImage set correct image
  break;
 case "As a Ridee":
  //groupImage set correct image
  break;
 case "My Recent Activities":
  //groupImage set correct image
  break;
}

// Get the group item
String listTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
// Set group name    
TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textGroup);
textView.setText(listTitle);
ImageView indicator = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupIndicator);
if (isExpanded) {
    indicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrowup);
} else {
    indicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrowdown);
}

return convertView;
}
```

It's not the most neat solution as if you change the group name this will break, but it will work for now. Better solution would be is to pass the groups as objects containing getName and getImageId.